# Как создавать 3d обьекты в JavaFX

Tags: javafx, 3d

Как создавать 3d обьекты в JavaFX и что для этого нужно. Желательно пример

Answer (score 2):

При создании сцены нужно выбрать конструктор указывающий что нужно создать сцену с поддержкой буфера глубины, ну и собственно добавляешь нужные фигуры и источник освещения прямо на сцену:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.PointLight;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.shape.Cylinder;
import javafx.scene.shape.Sphere;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication24 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // коробка с размерами сторон 100, 100, 100
        Box box = new Box(100, 100, 100);
        box.setTranslateX(150);
        box.setTranslateY(0);
        box.setTranslateZ(400);
        // сфера с радиусом 50
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50);
        sphere.setTranslateX(300);
        sphere.setTranslateY(-5);
        sphere.setTranslateZ(400);

        // цилиндр радиусом 40 и высотой 120
        Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(40, 120);
        cylinder.setTranslateX(500);
        cylinder.setTranslateY(-25);
        cylinder.setTranslateZ(600);

        // Создание точки освещения
        PointLight light = new PointLight();
        light.setTranslateX(350);
        light.setTranslateY(100);
        light.setTranslateZ(300);

        // Добавление фигур и освещения
        Group root = new Group(box, sphere, cylinder, light);

        // Создание сцены с поддержкой буфера глубины
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100, true);

        // Установка камеры для обзора трехмерных фигур
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);// создание камеры
        camera.setTranslateX(100);
        camera.setTranslateY(-50);
        camera.setTranslateZ(300);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Отрисовка трехмерных фигур");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Также можно создавать собственные фигуры с помощью класса MeshView.

Comment: Дополнительно можно посмотреть вот это руководство: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm

Comment: И вот тема про текстурирование объектов: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8/

Comment: а как добавлять кнопки, так же как и на обычную панель?

Comment: совершенно верно, создаете кнопку (например btn) и добавляете её на панель (в нашем случае new Group(box, sphere, cylinder, light, btn))

Comment: Вроде все сделал правильно, добавил кнопку b1 на root она не отображается

Comment: замените в вышеприведенном коде существующие строки на эти:
        // Добавление фигур и освещения
        Group root = new Group(box, sphere, cylinder, light, btn);

        // Создание сцены с поддержкой буфера глубины
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 200, true);
и добавьте
        Button btn = new Button("Button");
        btn.setTranslateX(450);
        btn.setTranslateY(100);
        btn.setTranslateZ(300);

Comment: Все получилось, проблема была в том что я изменял угол наклона камеры и т.д. и не учел это при изменении расположения кнопки по оси z. Спасибо